How to Cluster Highly Skewed DALY Data When Transformations and Clustering Algorithms Don't Help?
I’m working with a dataset of Disability-Adjusted Life Years (DALY) values with a high degree of skewness, as shown in the histogram below, where most values cluster near zero with a long tail extending towards higher values. My goal is to cluster this data for insights, but despite trying various transformations and clustering algorithms, the results remain unsatisfactory.
I've attempted the following:
Transformations: Log, Box-Cox, and Power transformations, but none have effectively normalized the distribution.
Clustering Algorithms: k-means,DBSCAN,  HDBSCAN,K prototype and Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) fail to provide meaningful clusters. k-means, in particular, struggles due to the skewness, and DBSCAN often marks many points as noise.
Given these challenges, does anyone have suggestions for alternative methods or approaches that could handle such skewed data in a way that allows for effective clustering? Or are there specific parameter tweaks that might help these methods handle the data better?
Additional Context:
The dataset contains high variability in DALY values across countries, with outliers even after anomaly detection and filtering.
I’m clustering based on DALY and other features(6 categorical features), such as SDI (Socio-Demographic Index), which also shows some degree of skew.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
